# Is there any difference between the different ways of giving an alias name to a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I have a table called "Employee" with a column name called "EmployeeName" and I know that all of these different queries will give all the employees in a table:

```
select EmployeeName from Employee;

select EmployeeName from Employee allEmployees;

select allEmployees.EmployeeName from Employee allEmployees;

select EmployeeName from Employee as allEmployees;
```

They both bring up all the employees in the table, is the difference between them in terms of query efficiency or running time?

I assume that for simple queries like this, there wouldn't be much difference, but if the above were part of some much longer query, would there be a better one to use? If so, why?

Comment: This is alias for table (short form, full is `tableName AS aliasName`)

Comment: 'somerandomword' would be the table alias. The queries look the same, but the 2nd would be safer as you wouldn't get a column name conflict if you included another table with the column name 'EmployeeName' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `somerandomword` as table alias there no difference between these two quires,they result same output because **there only one table**,
but if you have two **different tables with same column name** than this doesn't work because there is name conflict,at that time you have to use alias or table name.

Answer (score 1):

**Aliases** are used to give a temporary name to database table OR a column in a table. These are created to make column names more readable.

[**Wiki**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL))

```
SELECT somerandomword.EmployeeName from Employee somerandomword;
                                                 --------------
                                                   ^This is the alias name for your table
```

> Its safer to get data from columns, especially when we use multiple tables in SELECT query, like below syntax

**Syntax :**

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1 from Table_Name1 as t1, Table_Name2 as t2;
```

[**Sample Code**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm)